# Can't get code to complie

Tags: java, vector, nodes, prims-algorithm

I'm trying to learn Prim's algorithm and I'm using [this website](http://www.thecshandbook.com/Prim's) to do so, but I'm having trouble making the code part of it run. I'm confused with what goes in `public static int Prims(Vector<Vector<node>> adjList)` and how to get the code to compile and run. (New to java so excuse me if its a silly question).

edit: This is the code I'm trying to run:

```
class node implements Comparable<node> {
  int weight, index;
  public node(int weight, int index) {
     this.weight = weight;
     this.index = index;
  }
  public int compareTo(node e) {
     return weight - e.weight;
  }
}public static int Prims(Vector<Vector<node>> adjList) {
   // Current cost of MST.
   int cost = 0;
   int n = adjList.size();

   PriorityQueue<node> pq = new PriorityQueue<node>();

   // Keep track if each node is visited.
   boolean visited[] = new boolean[n];
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
     visited[i] = false;
   }

   // Number of nodes visited.
   int inTree = 1;

   // Mark starting node as visited.
   visited[0] = true;

   // Add all edges of starting node.
   for (int i = 0; i < adjList.get(0).size(); i++) {
     pq.add(adjList.get(0).get(i));
   }
   // Keep going until all nodes visited.
   while (!pq.isEmpty() && inTree < n) {
     // Get the edge with the smallest weight.
     node cur = pq.poll();
     // Skip if node already used.
     if (visited[cur.index]) {
       continue;
     }
     inTree++;
     visited[cur.index] = true;
     cost += cur.weight;
     // Add all the edges of the new node to the priority queue.
     for (int i = 0; i < adjList.get(cur.index).size(); i++) {
       pq.add(adjList.get(cur.index).get(i));
     }
   }
   // Graph not connected if number of nodes used is less than total nodes.
   if (inTree < n) {
     return -1;
   }

   return cost;
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please take some time to visit the [help] and also read [ask].  You have to show more of your code and explain more clearly what your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Your method `public static int Prims(Vector<Vector<node>> adjList)` does not appear to be a member of a class. It needs to be. The leading `}` on the line

```
}public static int Prims(Vector<Vector<node>> adjList) {
```

should probable be moved to the end of the file.

Answer (score -1):

If you do not use an IDE to compile and run a code you need to issue the following commands:

```
javac MyCode.java
java MyCode
```

where I suppose your code resides in a file named MyCode.java and there is no package defined.